# Need an algorithm in python to spot breakouts in price action trading

Tags: algorithmic-trading

I need an algorithm to spot breakouts in a given pair (in financial markets) using raw OHLC data thats received from API.

And the algorithm should help me spot prices levels. I am not sure if I am clear since I know the matter but I don't have programming background. In a basic sense the algorithm should spot a break out as in the following image.

Since I don't know anyone who develops algorithm like this I would appreciate some advise on how to get this algorithm complete.

Thanks for your time for reading.

[image: chart]

Comment: What algorithm do you expect to use? Why python?

Comment: my developper knows python but, he has no knowledge of trading, nothing I mean. It would be easier for him to understand. Thats why I stated python.

Comment: you need to explain under what condition this breakout happens, computer cannot spot on its own